# Finding prime numbers is giving me errors

Tags: c

I wanted to print the divisors of given range of numbers. It works alright. But when I try to modify it to put `****` at the end of the prime number's divisors it acts like bizarre.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int     a,start,rounds,b,c,k=0;

    printf("Please enter a number to start :");
    scanf("%d",&start);
    printf("Please enter how many numbers you want to print from that number :");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&rounds);

    for(a=start;a<=start+rounds;a++)
    {
         printf("\n\nThe divisors of number :%d are \n",a);

         for(b=1;b<=a;b++)
         {
             c=a%b;
             if(!c)
             {
                  k++;
                  printf("%d\n",b);
             }
          }
          //printf("%d",k);
          if((k==2)||(k==1))
             printf("***\n");
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

PS:- The trick I used to find a prime number is counting how many `printf` statement has been executed before loop ends. Is there any wrong with it? When I remove `//` from `printf` statement it prints like below.

```
start=========>k

  1   =========>1

  2   =========>3

  3   =========>5

  4   =========>8

  5   =========>10
```

Why is that?

Comment: Learn to indent your code properly. That helps finding a lot of problems.

Comment: `if((k==2)&&(k==1))`.k cannot have two values at the same time.

Comment: Your output doesn't appear to really be from the code that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

> if((k==2)&&(k==1))

There is no way in todays computers that k can be 2 **and** 1 at the same time. Maybe you meant to say if k is 2 **OR** k is 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `k` back to 0 in your outer loop

```
printf("\n\nThe divisors of number :%d are \n",a);
k = 0;
```

(And, as others have pointed out, you need an `||` operator rather than `&&` for the final test)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. k=o before the next round.And I corrected my mistake (&&===>||).